# How can I generate a histogram for the largest strongly connected component of a directed graph?

Tags: manipulate, graphs-and-networks, probability-or-statistics

With the help of several persons from this forum, I have written the following MMA `Code` using `Manipulate` to describe certain regions of a system.

```
<<IGraphM`;
<<BoolEval`;

SeedRandom[102];
mm = RandomReal[{0, 0.5}, {17, 17}];
vLabels = {1 -> AGR, 2 -> FIS, 3 -> CO1, 4 -> CO2, 5 -> MA1, 6 -> MA2,
7 -> EGW, 8 -> CST, 9 -> WHS, 10 -> HOT, 11 -> TSC, 12 -> FIN, 
13 -> EST, 14 -> ADM, 15 -> EDU, 16 -> HLT, 17 -> OSER};

selectBetween[θ1_, θ2_] := 
BoolEval[θ1 <= mm <= θ2];
subgraphBetween[θ1_, θ2_] := 
AdjacencyGraph[selectBetween[θ1, θ2],
PlotLabel -> θ1 <= Subscript[m, ij] < θ2, 
VertexSize -> 0.3, VertexLabels -> vLabels, ImagePadding -> 20, 
ImageSize -> 150];

Manipulate[
Grid[
{{"Digraph within the interval for " <> 
  ToString[Subscript[m, ij], TraditionalForm], 
 "Total number of edges in the interval", 
 "Histogram"}, {subgraphBetween[θ1, θ2], {EdgeCount[
   subgraphBetween[θ1, θ2]]}, 
 Histogram[{0}, {binlims = 
    Range[θ1, θ2, (θ2 - θ1)/
      nbars]}, (EdgeCount[subgraphBetween[##]] & @@@ 
     Partition[binlims, 2, 1] &), LabelingFunction -> Above]}} // 
Transpose
],
{{θ1, 0.035, "Threshold θ1 \!\(\*
StyleBox[\"≤\",\nFontFamily->\"Cambria\",\nFontSize->16,\n\
FontWeight->\"Plain\"]\)" <> 
ToString[Subscript[m, ij], TraditionalForm]}, 0.0001, 1.5, 
0.005}, {{θ2, 0.99, 
ToString[Subscript[m, ij], TraditionalForm] <> "\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"≤\",\nFontFamily->\"Cambria\",\nFontSize->16,\n\
FontWeight->\"Plain\"]\) Threshold θ2"}, 0.0001, 1.5, 0.005},
{{nbars, 10}, 1, 100, 1}
]
```

This `Code` produces:

[image]

As seen from this digraph, I trimmed the original digraph to focus on the interval: `0.01<= mm <0.06`and generated the histogram of the graph for the interval. So far, everything is fine.

My ultimate purpose is to replicate the above `Manipulate` code for the largest strongly connected component (SCC) of the graph (as illustrated below):

```
sa = SparseArray[selectBetween[0.01, 0.06]*mm];
gr = Graph[sa["NonzeroPositions"], EdgeWeight -> sa["NonzeroValues"], 
DirectedEdges -> True, EdgeStyle -> LightGray, 
VertexLabels -> vLabels];
SCCs = ConnectedComponents[gr];
sccLargest = MaximalBy[Length]@SCCs // Flatten;
grLargestSCC = HighlightGraph[gr, Subgraph[gr, sccLargest]]
Subgraph[gr, sccLargest, VertexLabels -> vLabels]
```

[image]

Although I find the largest SCC (i.e. the red subgraph), I failed to modify the `Manipulate` code to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Manipulate[sgb = subgraphBetween[θ1, θ2]; 
 sccLargest = MaximalBy[Length] @ ConnectedComponents[sgb] // Flatten; 
 Grid[{{"Digraph within the interval for " <> 
      ToString[Subscript[m, ij], TraditionalForm] <> "\nsubgraph - largestCC",
     "Total number of edges in the interval (subgraph)", 
     "Histogram (subgraph)"}, 
    {HighlightGraph[sgb, Subgraph[sgb, sccLargest]],
     {EdgeCount[Subgraph[sgb, sccLargest]]},
     Histogram[{0}, {binlims = Range[θ1, θ2, (θ2 - θ1)/nbars]}, 
      Apply[EdgeCount[Subgraph[subgraphBetween[##], sccLargest]] &, 
        Partition[binlims, 2, 1], {1}] &, 
      LabelingFunction -> Above]}} // Transpose], 
   {{θ1, 0.035,  "Threshold θ1 \!\(\*StyleBox[\"≤\",\nFontFamily->\"Cambria\",\n\
     FontSize->16,\nFontWeight->\"Plain\"]\)" <> 
      ToString[Subscript[m, ij], TraditionalForm]}, 0.0001, 1.5, 0.005}, 
   {{θ2, 0.99, 
     ToString[Subscript[m, ij], TraditionalForm] <> "\!\(\*
      StyleBox[\"≤\",\nFontFamily->\"Cambria\",\n\ FontSize -> 16, 
    \nFontWeight->\"Plain\"]\) Threshold θ2"}, 0.0001, 1.5, 0.005},
   {{nbars, 10}, 1, 100, 1}]
```

[image]